# symfony/console method not compatible with the interface it implements

Tags: php, symfony

I've got the following error when trying to use symfony/console:

`Declaration of Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle::ask(string $question, ?string $default = NULL, $validator = NULL) must be compatible with Symfony\Component\Console\Style\StyleInterface::ask(string $question, ?string $default = NULL, ?callable $validator = NULL)`

The method declaration is:
`public function ask(string $question, ?string $default = null, $validator = null)`

The interface declaration is:
`public function ask(string $question, ?string $default = null, callable $validator = null);`

This is the original class:
https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/619054da7627df1c2169c7aabe0df78f9320847c/Style/SymfonyStyle.php#L257

This is the interface:
https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/619054da7627df1c2169c7aabe0df78f9320847c/Style/StyleInterface.php#L88

I don't understand why the declaration is different. It's hard to believe this is an actual error with Symfony, I'm probably doing something wrong here. But what?

Answer (score -1):

I was using wrong PHP version: 7.1
This package requires at least PHP v7.2